# why would my heap increase steadily and full GC never happens?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I can see from the GC logs that the heap used memory is steadily increasing and the full GC never happens like say not even once in a day. The application has not crashed yet. What should I look for ? Any pointer would be very much helpful. I am running Java 7 on a linux machine.

Comment: It only performs a full GC when it has to.  If it hasn't performed a full GC, you haven't given it a reason to do so.

Comment: Do you have a memory leak or something somewhere?

Comment: Tenure generation GC called Major, Full GC is cleaning entire heap, you probably still have free memory in the heap. Instead focus on how often Major GC happens and how long  Stop the world pauses happen.

Comment: Also some gc logs would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Java process memory include JVM memory space (heap + few other areas) and non JVM memory (if you are using some native libraries in your JVM).

Normally heap never shirks - memory freed to be reused by JVM, but not released to OS (it depends on GC algorithm).

JVM have two options to control heap size `-Xms` and `-Xmx` which set initial size of heap and max possible ([actually a bit more than 2 options](http://blog.ragozin.info/2013/11/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html)).

Growing process memory footprint may or may not be an indication of memory leak.

You need to enable GC logging in JVM or use some JVM tool (e.g. JVisualVM) to verify if your live object population is growing or not.

Memory leaks in Java typically manifest itself as sequence of "Full GC" events with reducing intervals between.

You should not expect JVM garbage collector to release memory back to OS. Some algorithms cannot do it. Some (e.g. G1) can, but they may have over reasons not to do it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Why ? Because there is a memory leak somewhere or objects inflation. I advise you to run MAT : http://eclipse.org/mat